# How can i pass SQL query to Crystal Report ?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Hi im using 3 tier architecture..

```
Public Function SelectVoucher() As DataSet

    Try
        Squery = "select a.VoucherNo,convert(char(10),a.VoucherDate,120) as VoucherDate,
                    a.TotDebit,b.CustomerName as PartyName,c.Particulars
                    from spendmoney a,mcustomermaster b,spendmoneychild c
                    where a.partycode=b.customercode and a.voucherno=c.voucherno and 
                    a.voucherno=3"
        Return objdal.DBread(Squery)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function
```

this is the query i have been used,but crystal report is not displayed this query..

it displays all the fields..

but the original query answer is like:

```
3      2011-08-28        1500         prakash           www
```

This is the coding i have been used.

```
sub crystalreport

Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim objrpt As New CrystalReport10
ds = bol.SelectVoucher()


 If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
objrpt.SetDataSource(bol.SelectVoucher())
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objrpt
objrpt.Refresh()
CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End If

end sub
```

How can i pass the query to Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracted from the 'NET-CS2003_RAS-Unmanaged_CR115_Modify_Command-Table-SQL.zip' sample posted in [Crystal Reports for .NET SDK Samples](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports+for+.NET+SDK+Samples):

```
// Crystal Reports declarations
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument boReportDocument = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ISCDReportClientDocument boReportClientDocument;
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.DataDefController boDataDefController;
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.Database boDatabase;
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.CommandTable boCommandTable;

// Load the report using the CR .NET SDK and get a handle on the ReportClientDocument
boReportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("Command table report.rpt"));
boReportClientDocument = boReportDocument.ReportClientDocument;

// Use the DataDefController to access the database and the command table.
// Then display the current command table SQL in the textbox.
boDataDefController = boReportClientDocument.DataDefController;
boDatabase = boDataDefController.Database;
boCommandTable = (CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.CommandTable)boDatabase.Tables[0];
boCommandTable.CommandText = sQuery;

// Clean up
boReportDocument.Close();
boReportDocument.Dispose();
```